# HD wallet parameters clarification

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, seed

I'm using [HD Address Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hdaddressgenerator) to create an HD wallet:

```
let mnemonic = "voyage blind unit shoulder yellow attitude mule all hire above obvious swap"
let bip84 = HdAddGen.withMnemonic(mnemonic, false, "BTC", true, 84)
```

The object that I'm getting back contains the fields:

- `bip32Seed`
- `bip32RootKey`
- `accountXprivKey`
- `accountXpubKey`
- `bip32XprivKey`
- `bip32XpubKey`

I went over [HD Wallets](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets) and [Extended Keys](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/extended-keys), as I understand:

- `bip32XprivKey` is the extended private key
- `bip32XpubKey` is the extended public key
- `bip32Seed` is the seed that is derived from the mnemonic

Does it make sense?
Also, what are `bip32RootKey`, `accountXprivKey` and `accountXpubKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 84 parameter means that you want BIP84 addresses then:

```
bip32RootKey: this would be the root EC private key
accountXprivKey: this would be the extended private key at derivation path m/84’/0’/0’
accountXpubKey: this would be the extended public key at derivation path m/84’/0’/0’
```